# Processing line shapefiles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, vector, arcgis-10.4

I have a line featureclass with many segments (for example roads or waterways). I want to merge line feature segments that touch each other until the next crossing. The picture shows an example. After the geoprocessing operation I want to have one long line, two middle lines and one short line.

I know how to do it with the editing toolbar for some features manually, but how do I do it for ALL features of the whole layer?

The current segmentation doesn't make sense in my project.

How do I do it in ArcMap 10.4 ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) with the `Unsplit Lines` parameter set to `UNSPLIT_LINES` and `Multipart` parameter set to `SINGLE_PART`.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! I knew dissolve, but the combination of UNSPLIT_LINES and SINGLE_PART works magic, thanks a lot!!